# How to make popupwindow size exceed dialog window size?

Tags: android, android-widget, popupwindow, android-dialogfragment

I have use Popupwindow for auto-suggestion popup in a dialogFragment. On portrait, that popup doesn't reach soft keyboard (popup look small), it seem like its size is limited by dialog windown size. I want the popup reach soft keyboard (look bigger). How to make popupwindow exceed dialog window?

Note : I have try to setClippingEnable to fasle, but popup is growth exceed keyboard and screen.

Answer (score 3):

Set this boolean for your popup window object and the pop up size will exceed the dialog size.

```
popupWindow.setClippingEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are my code

```
    popUp = new PopupWindow(view, w, h);
    popUp.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    popUp.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    popUp.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
    popUp.setInputMethodMode(PopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED);
    popUp.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
                popUp.dismiss();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    private void updatePopUp(EditText input) { 
      popUp.setWidth(input.getWidth());
      popUp.showAsDropDown(input);
      popUp.update();
    }
```

I think this code don't have problem because I have use it in other class, but the problem is when I implement it in dialog Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
PopupWindow mPop=new PopupWindow("View for popup","hgt(int)","width(int)","focusable(boolean)");
```